# How can I visualize a Multilevel SEM?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, structural-equation-modeling

I'm looking for advice on how to visualize a multilevel structural equation model. The usual approaches (using semTools) don't work.

Does anyone here have an idea?

Comment: This paper will help, to start with. http://curran.web.unc.edu/files/2015/03/CurranBauer2007.pdf There are no tools (AFAIK).

Comment: Clarification:  ¿are you looking to visualize the model? or ¿are you looking to visualize the output/results?

Comment: My goal was to show the path diagram including standardized loadings.

Comment: If you are look at the Mplus Manual https://www.statmodel.com/download/usersguide/MplusUserGuideVer_8.pdf p. 271 & p. 276, there are examples of how to draw a MLM model in the SEM framework.